# JPA @Formula without Schema Name or Configure with entity class

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, `A_TABLE` and `B_TABLE`. in `A_TABLE` entity class need on formula which has `B_TABLE` column combination like below code,

**Working Code:**

```
A_TABLEEntity {

    @Column("BM_NAME_I")
    private String bmdName;

    @Formula("(select b.LAST_NAME || ', '||b.FIRST_NAME||' ('||b.BM_NAME||')' 
    from BR_SCHEMA.B_TABLE  b where UPPER(b.BM_NAME)=UPPER(BM_NAME_I))")

    private string nameCombinationB;

}
```

**Need solution in Formula :**

1) Is it possible to provide any way to give `B_TABLEEntity` class instead of   `B_TABLE` directly and columns from `B_table` entity class?

And I have tried with entity class its throwing error, - table or view does not exist

2) Is it possible to avoid to give `SCHEMA` name in `B_TABLE` before in formula?

And without schema error is throwing - table or view does not exist

Please help me above `@Formula` JPA code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely look here: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula

According to the described comment, @Formula takes only native sql and the article warns you about coupling to the specific database in some cases.

> You should be aware that the @Formula annotation takes a native SQL
>   clause which may affect database portability.

As the @Formula requires native SQL, you should always include schema. I think that some DB's have default schema that does not need to be defined explicitly.

For some advanced operations, I would probably provide some annotation like @PostLoad and load desired properties using good old entitymanager or direct jdbc.

Maybe these links may help:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching